findMany() prisma This expression is not callable
this is the code:
  // Fetch messages without type assertion
  const messages = await prisma.contactMessage.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: "desc",
    },
  });

this is the full error:
This expression is not callable.
Each member of the union type '((args?: SelectSubset<T, ContactMessageFindManyArgs> | undefined) => PrismaPromise<...>) | ((args?: SelectSubset<...> | undefined) => PrismaPromise<...>)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
